R arrow - add a column to a Parquet dataset and write as a new file?
Is there a way to add a column (from a vector) to a Parquet dataset opened with arrow (open_dataset) in R (i.e., not loading the table in RAM for larger-than-memory tables)?
I was able to add a column containing the same integer recycled for each row and directly write to a new Parquet file, but I could not add a vector (of same length) containing several values.
library(data.table)
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
library(duckdb)

dt = data.table(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c("a", "b", "c"))
write_parquet(dt, "dt.parquet")
dt |> mutate(z = z) # works as expected for object in memory

ds |> mutate(z = 1) |> write_parquet("ds1.parquet")
read_parquet("ds1.parquet") # adds the integer to each row
#       x      y     z
#   <num> <char> <num>
#1:     1      a     1
#2:     2      b     1
#3:     3      c     1

z = c(4,5,6)
ds = open_dataset("dt.parquet")

ds |> mutate(z = z) |> write_parquet("ds2.parquet")
# error: In z = z, only values of size one are recycled
# Call collect() first to pull data into R.

# trying with duckdb with no luck (recycles z on each row):
ds |> to_duckdb() |> mutate(z = z) |> to_arrow() |> write_parquet("ds2.parquet")
read_parquet("ds2.parquet")
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#      x y      z$``   $``   $``
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a         4     5     6
#2     2 b         4     5     6
#3     3 c         4     5     6



Am I missing something to do this? Or could it work with an approach using chunks as shown here?

EDIT
Tried a suggestion to convert to an arrow table and then use cbind (ds |> as_arrow_table() |> cbind(z=z)) but apparently it loads data in memory (even if the created object is an Arrow table pointer with small size, and peakRAM shows zero RAM consumption, Rstudio shows an increase in RAM consumption and can lead to an out-of-memory error with large data).

A couple of ideas. First, update the schema/metadata manually. Second, the data type for the z=c(4,5,6) is struct so it thinks z is a data.frame per https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/data_types.html. Third, you might need to create the column in its own parquette file and then recreate the dataset (not table) with the old and new files per https://arrow.apache.org/docs/2.0/r/reference/write_parquet.html My best bet right now is that the recycling is happening due to using read_parquette vs. open_dataset.
